# How can I match dates based on a secondary field?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery, I'm trying to associate an event start time with an end time that is defined as the maximum time where the event type doesn't match the event type of the start time.

Here's an example to illustrate my issue:

Original dataset:

```
Name    Event     Event Type    Datetime
****    ******    **********    ****************
Bob     Tennis    Start         2017-02-17 8:00
Bob     Tennis    Playing       2017-02-17 8:10
Bob     Tennis    Playing       2017-02-17 8:20
Bob     Tennis    Playing       2017-02-17 8:30
Bob     Tennis    Playing       2017-02-17 8:50
Bob     Tennis    Start         2017-02-17 10:00
Bob     Tennis    Playing       2017-02-17 10:30
Bob     Bowling   Start         2017-02-18 2:15
Bob     Bowling   Playing       2017-02-18 2:18
```

Desired table:

```
Name    Event     Start Datetime      End Datetime
****    ******    ****************    ****************
Bob     Tennis    2017-02-17 8:00     2017-02-17 8:50
Bob     Tennis    2017-02-17 10:00    2017-02-17 10:30
Bob     Bowling   2017-02-18 2:15     2017-02-18 2:18
```

I know the solution must involve `partition` and `max` functions, but I'm not sure how to find the max datetime where the event type doesn't match that of the row in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below, should give you an idea

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT Name, Event, MIN(DateTime) AS StartDateTime, MAX(DateTime) AS EndDateTime
FROM (
  SELECT Name, Event, EventType, DateTime, 
    COUNTIF(EventType = 'Start') OVER(PARTITION BY Name, Event ORDER BY DateTime ) AS grp
  FROM yourTable
)
GROUP BY Name, Event, grp
```

You can test it with below dummy data

```sql
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 'Bob' AS Name, 'Tennis' AS Event, 'Start' AS EventType, '2017-02-17 08:00' AS DateTime UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'Tennis', 'Playing', '2017-02-17 08:10' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'Tennis', 'Playing', '2017-02-17 08:20' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'Tennis', 'Playing', '2017-02-17 08:30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'Tennis', 'Playing', '2017-02-17 08:50' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'Tennis', 'Start', '2017-02-17 10:00' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'Tennis', 'Playing', '2017-02-17 10:30' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'Bowling', 'Start', '2017-02-18 02:15' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bob', 'Bowling', 'Playing', '2017-02-18 02:18' 
)
```

Comment: very clever solution!

Comment: Incredible! All hail SQL Master Mikhail! Thanks so much!